# Remove <p></p> after images

Tags: functions, images, html

I have an issue with `<p></p>` tags appearing after my `<img....>`. Here is what appears when I view the generated page on my localhost...

```
<img src="/wp-content/themes/wunderful/assets/images/feedback-danielle.png" alt="Danielle Johnson Deal Town FC Treasurer">
<p></p>
```

Notice the randomly generated `<p></p>` above, underneath the image. I haven't added this myself inside of the WordPress editor, so why is it appearing? How do I fix it please?

I have previously added this to my functions.php file to cancel out other non-necessary

tags. Perhaps it could be expanded upon to fix this issue too?

```
function filter_ptags_on_images($content)
{
    // do a regular expression replace...
    // find all p tags that have just
    // <p>maybe some white space<img all stuff up to /> then maybe whitespace </p>
    // replace it with just the image tag...
    return preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<a .*>)?\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1\2\3', $content);
}

// we want it to be run after the autop stuff... 10 is default.
add_filter('the_content', 'filter_ptags_on_images');
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a slightly different variant to your code :

```
function filter_ptags_on_images($content) {
    $content = preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<a .*>)?\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1\2\3', $content);
    return preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<iframe .*>*.<\/iframe>)\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1', $content);
}
add_filter('the_content', 'filter_ptags_on_images');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
function filter_ptags_on_images($content) {
    $content = str_replace( "><p></p>", "", $content );
}
add_filter('the_content', 'filter_ptags_on_images');
```

Let it give a try